# PHP: How to take Date/Time from a form, format to a String and then insert into database?

Tags: php, date, datetime, formatting

So I've got a form which has loads of different things that go into a database, when I added the date and time checkers into the form, they go into the database as a string 
(Example: "2018-05-29" "10:47:00.000000" is how they look when they go in ["Here"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAZN3.png))

I want to reformat these so that when they are inserted into the database they show up as actual words

(Example: "29th May 2018" "Tuesday 29th May" "10:47 AM/PM" something along these lines)

So that when I use my php and grab the data from the database and display it on the page it'll show the actual words instead of just numbers.

(Note: Yes I've tried going the other way around and converting it when it comes out of the database, but because of the way I'm displaying things, it won't work)

```
<?php

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Select Database
mysqli_select_db($conn, "czt_database");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "Connected successfully";

$game = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Game']);
$map = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Map']);
$challenge = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Challenge']);
$extra = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Extras']);
$players = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Players']);
$entryfee = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Type']);
$entrycost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Fee']);
$prizemoney = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Prize']);
$entrymax = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Entries']);
$startdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Start-date']);
$starttime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Start-time']);
$enddate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['End-date']);
$endtime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['End-time']);
$rules = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Rules']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tournaments (tournament_game, tournament_map, tournament_challenge, tournament_extra, tournament_players, tournament_entryfee, tournament_entrycost, tournament_prize, tournament_entrymax, tournament_startdate, tournament_starttime, tournament_enddate, tournament_endtime, tournament_rules) 
        VALUES ('$game', '$map', '$challenge', '$extra', '$players', '$entryfee', '$entrycost', '$prizemoney', '$entrymax', '$startdate', '$starttime', '$enddate', '$endtime', '$rules');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location:../Create-A-Tournament.html");

?>
```

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ , Everything you need

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php , http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

Comment: You need to format the date returned from the database. You can do this by using the strtotime()-function and the date()-function.

Comment: You should also look into using Prepared Statements instead of building your query like that. It makes your code more verbose and less prone to mistakes which can cause SQL Injection bugs.

Comment: _"they go into the database as a string"_ - Are you storing dates and time as strings? Those columns should be "date" and "time"-types in the database.

Comment: Yeah, the columns they go into are already date/time types in the database. I mean in the date picker when you choose the date it shows up as. "2018-05-29" and "7:29 AM" and when in the database it also shows up as "2018-05-29" and "7:29:00.00000". I wanna try to make these appear in the database as "Monday 29th May" or "7:29 AM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code something like below

```
$startDate=date("l dS M Y", strtotime($_POST['start-date'])); //This will give result as Tuesday 7th May 2018.

$startTime=date("h:i A", strtotime($_POST['start-time']));  // This returns time as 04:56 AM/PM

$startdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $startDate);
$starttime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $startTime);
```

Then you can use the above variables to store in DB.

Hope it helps.

Comment: [Nope no luck?? Or am I doing something completely wrong, idk aha. (*Picture*)](https://imgur.com/a/qUKdtnS)

Comment: @Nanikos: I have updated the code. please check if it works.

Comment: All good, I ended up changing the way it displays the data entirely and after a lot of trial and error got it working :) Your post did help me though to get to that point, so thanks!

Comment: @Nanikos: Glad it helped.